# Change the style KeyboardDatePicker Material UI component

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I was using Material UI components for creating a React Js app.

First, I wanted to change the width and height of [KeyboardDatePicker](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker) from Material UI component.

Here was the first condition:
[image: First condition]

and here was the code for the start and end date pickers:

```js
<div>
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker 
            disableToolbar
            label="Start Date"
            variant="inline"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            format="dd/MM/yyyy"
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
                'aria-label': 'change date',
            }}
            keyboardIcon={<TodayIcon style={{color: colors.customCornFlowerBlue}}/>}
            value={startDate}
            onChange={changeStartDate}
        />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
</div>
<div>
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker 
            disableToolbar
            label="End Date"
            variant="inline"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            format="dd/MM/yyyy"
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
                'aria-label': 'change date',
            }}
            keyboardIcon={<TodayIcon style={{color: colors.customCornFlowerBlue}}/>}
            value={endDate}
            onChange={changeEndDate}
        />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
</div>
```

Then I tried to change the width and height of both date pickers by adding InputProps and style prop to both date pickers:

```js
<div>
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker 
            disableToolbar
            label="Start Date"
            variant="inline"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            format="dd/MM/yyyy"
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
                'aria-label': 'change date',
            }}
            keyboardIcon={<TodayIcon style={{color: colors.customCornFlowerBlue}}/>}
            value={startDate}
            onChange={changeStartDate}
            InputProps={{
                style: {
                    fontSize: 14,
                    height: 44
                }
            }}
            style={{
                width: 232
            }}
        />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
</div>
<div>
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker 
            disableToolbar
            label="End Date"
            variant="inline"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            format="dd/MM/yyyy"
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
                'aria-label': 'change date',
            }}
            keyboardIcon={<TodayIcon style={{color: colors.customCornFlowerBlue}}/>}
            value={endDate}
            onChange={changeEndDate}
            InputProps={{
                style: {
                    fontSize: 14,
                    height: 44
                }
            }}
            style={{
                width: 232
            }}
        />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
</div>
```

and here was the result:
[image]

As we can see that the position of the label/hint text was not centerized vertically.

**So how could I change the style of for this date picker?**

These were the properties I wanted:

1. Width: 246 px
2. Height: 44 px
3. The label/hint text is centerized vertically

Answer (score 6):

You can use style prop to do it , pass props value like this `style={{width:"246px",height:"44px"}}`

```
 <KeyboardDatePicker 
            disableToolbar
            label="Start Date"
            variant="inline"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            format="dd/MM/yyyy"
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
                'aria-label': 'change date',
            }}
            keyboardIcon={<TodayIcon style={{color: colors.customCornFlowerBlue}}/>}
            value={startDate}
            onChange={changeStartDate}
            InputProps={{
                style: {
                    fontSize: 14,
                    height: 44
                }
            }}
             style={{width:"246px",height:"44px"}}
        />
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried it before but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue and ended up wrapping the MUI element with divs and applying the styles to the div. Dunno if this is a good solution but works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).